# Windows server 2012 R2 VM doesn't see full space on virtual disk

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, partition, disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement

I have a windows server 2012 R2 VM on vmware esxi 6.7. Have 2 virtual disks for C and D partitions respectively. Partition C - thin provision, part D - thick provision lazy zeroed.
I extended second virtual disk by 100 GB.
Then increased partition in OS by 100 GB. There was an error (don't remember what) and disk space hasn't changed.
Rescanned disks, used diskpart, rebooted server - it doesn't help though.

Maybe somebody faced such an issue...

[Disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L14M5.jpg) - screenshot. Strange picture...

Comment: Are you sure that your VMDK for OS was actually extended? Did you check the VMDK size?

Comment: Yes, VMDK was actually extended. I checked twice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article helped - https://www.tecklyfe.com/extend-volume-error-the-parameter-is-incorrect-in-windows-server/

I didn't use checkdisk, because it's a big partition. But diskpart `extend filesystem`
 command helped.

Answer (score 3):

That can be a Disk Management interface issue. Please try to refresh the view and rescan the disks once again. That can be done by selecting **Action > Rescan Disks** in the upper menu.

If that does not help, try updating the storage provider cache. That is done by running following Powershell commander from elevated Powershell prompt:

```
Update-StorageProviderCache -DiscoveryLevel Full
```

You can also restart the virtual machine. That might also help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Rescan and reboot didn't help